# Refs to # in a definition don't parse inJson.net schema

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I have a schema that has a 'manager' property which is a user object:

```
{
  "id": "foo.com/schemas/user",
  "manager": {
    "anyOf": [{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
    }],
    "title": "Manager"
}
```

The #/definitions/user schema is:

```
"definitions": {
  "user": {
    "$ref": "#"
  }
}
```

This results in a "*Error when resolving schema reference '#'. Path 'definitions.user'*" error.

Addressing the user with "$ref": "#" from the manager property isn't an option as we are using the definition to help build the UI and need a common definition.

Edit: added the "id" property which was a critical omission in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
{
  "id": "http://foo.com/schemas/user",  
  "properties":{  
    "manager":{  
      "anyOf":[  
        {  
          "$ref":"#/definitions/user"
        }
      ],
      "title":"Manager"
    }
  },
  "definitions":{  
    "user":{  
      "$ref":"#"
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/33

Edit: Added fixed "id" field with http:// qualification added.